# Got a macro running, changed pc and now its not running anymore, giving me a error

Tags: excel, vba

This was working before, now im trying it on my pc and not working and giving me that error message, any clues?

```
Private Sub Novo_Teste_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call PEM
Call VouF
Call PD
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
Sub PEM() 'Perguntas Escolha Multipla
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("O1:O50")
    rng.ClearContents
    ActiveSheet.Range("O1").Formula2 = "=INDEX(UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(1000,1,1,N1,TRUE)),SEQUENCE(B7))"
    rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
Sub VouF() ' Perguntas de Verdadeiro ou Falso
 Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("R1:R50")
    rng.ClearContents
    ActiveSheet.Range("R1").Formula2 = "=INDEX(UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(1000,1,1,Q1,TRUE)),SEQUENCE(B8))"
    rng.Value = rng.Value
 End Sub
```

...... and it goes on the same way, but for diferent sub

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `ActiveSheet` is the sheet you are hoping this code will work on? Seems risky. When you hit the `Debug` button, which line is highlighted?

Comment: Are you sure that your version of Excel supports Dynamic Array formulas and `.Formula2`?

Comment: actually that may be the problem, how can i check that, and if not how can i get the right suplements or so?

Comment: the line highlighted is
ActiveSheet.Range("O1").Formula2 = "=INDEX(UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(1000,1,1,N1,TRUE)),SEQUENCE(B7))"

Comment: Seems your version of Excel doesn't support Dynamic Array formulas.

Comment: ok thx alot, will try to get a more update excel version. thx alot for the help